# Is it real to stop( exit from location ) execute location with good return code in nginx?

Tags: nginx, gitlab

Main question - is it real to create location with exclude by uri ( or do not execute location rules if some uri were founded )?
I have gitlab 12 СE ( 12.9.2 (ac5568eb5d8) ) with nginx from gitlab itself (nginx 1.16.1 sha256:f11c2a6d )

So, i am trying to proxy_pass specific url from gitlab with exclude, if specific uri contain ( i.e - proxy_passing everything from location `/test/lfs_lock_test.git/info/lfs/locks` ( or `^.*.git/info/lfs/locks` ) but if that uri contain `&lockservice=true` - do not execute this location and not proxy_pass that url ( like are `/test/lfs_lock_test.git/info/lfs/locks?path=.gitattributes&lockservice=true` )
so i can catch specific uri ( `if ( $args ~ "lockservice=true" )` ), but how i can stop execute this location for that url ( without 404 )?

```
location /test/lfs_lock_test.git/info/lfs/locks{
 if ( $args ~ "lockservice=true" ) {
  return 404;
  }
 rewrite ^/test/lfs_lock_test.git/(.*) /$1 break;
 proxy_pass https://localhost:5002;
 access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/lfs_lock_access.log gitlab_access;
 error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/lfs_lock_error.log debug;
}
```

This is part of gitlab-http.conf ( auto-generated file ) - it mean i have something like that inside gitlab-http.conf:

```
  location / {
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_pass  http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found with help of nginx community ( Maxim Kulik ):
So, add new error_page and return that page in if block:

```
error_page 420 = @special_location;

location @special_location {
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_pass  http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }

location /test/lfs_lock_test.git/info/lfs/locks{
 if ( $args ~ "lockservice=true" ) {
  return 420;
  }
 rewrite ^/test/lfs_lock_test.git/(.*) /$1 break;
 proxy_pass https://localhost:5002;
 access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/lfs_lock_access.log gitlab_access;
 error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/lfs_lock_error.log debug;
}
```